# Choppy UIImageView Resizing with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to resize a `UIImageView`. Applying a simple `CGAffineTransform` works, but it resizes it based on the top left corner, whereas I want to resize it based on the center of the image. I can achieve the desired result with the following code

```
-(IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
UIImageView *view = [recognizer view];
float scale = recognizer.scale;
view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,  0, view.bounds.size.height*scale, view.bounds.size.width*scale);
recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

The problem is that when I use this code, the image gets all glitchy and choppy as it resizes. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be doing this the hard way.  Suggest you consider adding you `UIImageView` to a `UIScrollView`, and let the scroll view do the work for you.  E.g.:

Header with `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end
```

Implementation showing the setup of the scroll view that allows zooming:

```
#import "MyScrollViewController.h"

#define MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR 1
#define MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR 5

@interface MyScrollViewController () {
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@end

@implementation MyScrollViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR,
                                    self.view.bounds.size.height * MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR);
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR;

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_name.png"]];
    imageView.frame = scrollView.frame;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

#pragma mark - Scroll view delegate methods

-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return imageView;
}

@end
```

If you want to know when panning and zooming is occurring, what the zoom scale is, etc., implement additional `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.  For example:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)zoomedScrollingView{
    float zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale;
    // Do something with zoomScale...
}
```

Comment: This works, and it seems to resize based on a center position, but when the resizing ends, it snaps to the top left corner. Even when I use code in `scrollViewDidEndZooming` to reset the frame to the same position as before, it still snaps to the top left first